# DCEL data structure edge refinement algorithm (edge cases)

Tags: gis, polygon, computational-geometry

I'm trying to connect two polygons that are described as DCEL data structure and find it hard to do so at some edge cases where, for example, edges intersect with each other at their interior or overlap each other.

Here's the definition of the problem:

- The polygons are of rectangular shape with straight edges (edges at vertices make straight angles)
- There are no more than 8 edges that meet at the vertex. The only case where it's possible is that all 4 polygons meet at single vertex (aka 4 rectangles)
- It's impossible to have more than 2 edges intersecting in their interior
- It's impossible that polygons intersect not on segments. All intersections are done on edges and all of them are mix of overlapping cases or interior intersections
- There are no holes in polygons
- Dissolving internal faces is not allowed here. Edge in between still must be present

If this helps the polygons are representing imaginary regions enclosed under the imaginary country that's why they meet at edges only.

Here are some examples of polygons:

Case 1:

[Overlapping edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkvbT.png)

Case 2:

[One edge contains another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSyT1.png)

PS: Right now I'm reading Bergs 'Computational Geometry' and trying to practice in DCEL implementation

PSS: In addition I've read a lot of info across the Internet regarding handling subdivision overlapping, but haven't seen the explanation about how to handle such cases. What I think here is that I need to handle edge removal while Berg does not tell this in his book.

Also extra source: same Berg, but with more fancy images

https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/b201/_media/courses/cg/lectures/09-intersect-split.pdf (p. 26/96)

Comment: Do you call "connecting" the construction of the union of polygons ?

Comment: By geometric tests on the edges, find the starting and ending point of the edge-overlap region. Then you can insert these two points on the edges lacking them. Now you can merge by rearranging the pointers. (In fact, you will rearrange two loops with two common vertices, to the union of the polygons and a dead loop which is the degenerate intersection.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure about word "union" here as I think it is more than just connecting polygons like dissolving faces into which is not needed here (I'll update the question). So edge in between of two polygons must still be present. Regarding points. Following Bergs algorithm all vertices are stored in a single resulting DCEL which then must be "fixed" by performing sweep line approach (fix connections at each event point), but it's not clear how to handle already existing edges and vertices. Looks like I need some dict for fast search of already existing edge...

Comment: ... and only then create new. Other thing is what should be done in case if I have two already existing edges. How to handle data merging if so?

Comment: The "extra source" has great slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after tons of trials and errors I found the solution to my problem. It's not ideal because I still don't know the 'correct' answer on how to split edges when they are neighboring to each other for arbitrary polygon, but have a solution to my problem that I was trying to solve.

According to the algorithm that Berg described in his book edges must be refined using sweep line algorithm. Previous and next edge must be selected in the CCW or CW order (CCW = counter clockwise, CW = clockwise) depending in what direction edge is pointing, but it's hard to do so when you have overlapping edges. Additional complexity here will be that the edge consists of two half edges and it's a nightmare to refine both of them according to simplified algorithm described above. Instead, what we can do here is to forget about two half edges and use only one. It will always have incident face but no twin. In this case overlapping is detected perfectly using sweep line algorithm and polygon stitching becomes straightforward: the overlapping edges become twins to each other when edge refinement is done (splitting edge at the event point in case if edge contains it in the interior). When edge is split the other edge that belongs to another polygon becomes its twin

It looks a bit messy without thorough explanation, but I'll attach image that will show what I mean by that

[image: Algorithm in action]

On the image you can see edges like `a2` that gets split into two new edges - `a2'` and `a2''` plus old shrunk `a2`. Refinement of `a2` was done at two points - `v5` and `v8`. Each point is a beginning of the new half edge and the end of previous one. When we have two edges that are ending at a point (it's impossible to have more than 2 edges in my problem) we mark them as twins (`b4` and `a2'`). Resolving next and previous here is really easy.

To bypass the contour of stitched polygon (black lines) you can use info about the twin of next edge. If it has a twin then switch to the twins next edge at next step (`next_edge = a2'.twin.next` is the same as `next_edge = b4.next`)

PS: it will not work for case when you have multiple polygons overlapping at the same edge. It's hard to make twins in such case, but it's a question whether the correct solution exists or not?